# Retrieving token from localStorage

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, token

Basically I'm trying to return data from my db (MongoDB), and I'm having the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401
>
> (Unauthorized) createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request
> failed with status code 401
> at createError (createError.js:16)
> at settle (settle.js:17)
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)

The page loads but it doesn't show the data, I tested the api via Postman and the route is working smoothly.

My code looks like this:

*services / course.js*

```
import Api from "./api";

const CourseService = {
  index: () => Api.get('/courses', {
    headers: {'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem('token')}
  }),
}

export default CourseService;
```

*components/course/index.jsx*

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from 'reactstrap';
import ListCourses from './list';
import CourseService from '../../services/course';
import { push as Menuz } from 'react-burger-menu'

const Courses = (props) => {
  const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]);
  const [current_course, setCurrentCourse] = useState({ title: "", body: "", id: "" });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCourses();
  }, []);

  async function fetchCourses() {
    const response = await CourseService.index();
    if (response.data.length >= 1) {
      setCourses(response.data.reverse())
      setCurrentCourse(response.data[0])
    }
  }

  const selectCourse = (id) => {
    const course = courses.find((course) => {
      return course._id === id;
    })
    setCurrentCourse(course);
  }

  return(
    <Fragment>
      <ListGroup className="courses" id="courses">
          <Menuz
            pageWrapId={"courses-editor"}
            isOpen={props.isOpen}
            onStateChange={(state) => props.setIsOpen(state.isOpen)}
            disableAutoFocus
            outerContainerId={"courses"}
            customBurgerIcon={false}
            
          >
            <p>List...</p>
          </Menuz>
        
        
        <ListGroupItem className="courses-editor" id="courses-editor">
          <ListCourses courses={courses}
            selectNote={selectCourse}
            current_note={current_course} />
        </ListGroupItem>
      </ListGroup>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
export default Courses;
```

*components/courses/list/index.jsx*

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem, ListGroupItemHeading, ListGroupItemText, Badge } from 'reactstrap';
import Moment from 'moment';

const ListCourses = (props) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {props.courses.lenght}
      <ListGroup>
        {props.courses.map((item, key) => 
        <ListGroupItem key={key} onclick={() => props.selectCourse(item._id)} active={item === props.current_course}>
          <ListGroupItemHeading> {item.title.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "").substring(0,15)} <Badge pill>{Moment(item.created_at).format('DD/MM')}</Badge> </ListGroupItemHeading>
          <ListGroupItemText>
            {item.body.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "").substring(0,120)}
          </ListGroupItemText>
          <ListGroupItemText>lorem</ListGroupItemText>
        </ListGroupItem> )}
      </ListGroup>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default ListCourses;
```

PS: I'm starting with React and Node, so any hint of what I can study further is valid. If you need any more information about the code I can also edit it.

Comment: Where do you do the setItem

Comment: I'm utilizing setCourses at courses/index.jsx

Comment: Does `localStorage.getItem('token')` returns anything (rather than `undefined`)? If not, the problem not in this code.

Comment: so, works perfectly but with two apostrophes like this ""tokencodehere"" can be this?